# expo-modules-autolinking version

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo

i am trying to build my app developed with react native expo but expo doctor return an error:

```js
Expected package expo-modules-autolinking@~1.0.0
Found invalid:
  expo-modules-autolinking@0.8.1
  (for more info, run: npm why expo-modules-autolinking)
Expected package @expo/config-plugins@^5.0.2
Found invalid:
  @expo/config-plugins@4.1.5
  @expo/config-plugins@4.1.5
  @expo/config-plugins@2.0.4
  @expo/config-plugins@5.0.1
  @expo/config-plugins@4.1.5
  @expo/config-plugins@4.1.5
  @expo/config-plugins@4.1.5
  (for more info, run: npm why @expo/config-plugins)
Expected package @expo/prebuild-config@^5.0.5
Found invalid:
  @expo/prebuild-config@5.0.3
  @expo/prebuild-config@4.0.4
  (for more info, run: npm why @expo/prebuild-config)
```

I have found many solutions but none have solved my problem.

- i have upgraded expo
- i manually edited my package.json file by adding
  "resolutions": {
  "expo-modules-autolinking": "~1.0.0"
  }
  }
- I updated the expo models to the latest version
- I uninstalled and installed npm and expo

unfortunately I could not find the solution

Answer (score 3):

I hope you figured out what was happening, since I'm a bit late to the party. However I had the exact same problem today after upgrading an older project from expo SDK44 to SDK48. I've followed the instructions on the expo blog, but still got all those prebuild support packages that failed.
After spending some time on it I figured out this was because of on old dependency that `expo install --fix` doesn't remove. The one in question was `expo-app-loading`, hope this helps future visitors of this question out.

Comment: Eas build failed expo 48 : https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/21423